# AngularJs Routing Module is not redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

Whenever I browse to localhost:xxxx/ the login page will show up but when I enter data and submit it, it does not redirect me to student page but stays on the same login page. The data entered is already mapped on the url. And also I haven't included any user validation so whatever I enter should redirect me to the student page.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app="ngRoutingDemo">
    <h1>Angular Routing Demo</h1>

    <div ng-view>

    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('ngRoutingDemo', ['ngRoute']);

        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            }).when('/student/:username', {
                templateUrl: '/student.html',
                controller: 'studentController'
            }).otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/"
            });

            app.controller("loginController", function ($scope, $location) {

                $scope.authenticate = function (username) {
                    // write authentication code here..
                    alert('authenticate function is invoked');
                    $location.path('/student/' + username)
                };

            });

            app.controller("studentController", function ($scope, $routeParams) {
                $scope.username = $routeParams.username;
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="loginForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="User Name" class="form-control" ng-model="userName" required />
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="loginForm.userName.$touched && loginForm.userName.$invalid">Please enter User Name.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" required />
            <span ng-show="loginForm.password.$touched && loginForm.password.$error.required">Please enter Password.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-3" ng-click="authenticate(userName)" />
</form>
```

**student.html**

```
<div>
    <p>Welcome {{username}}</p>
    <a href="/">Log out</a>
</div>

<form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submitStudnetForm()" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" ng-model="student.firstName" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" id="lastName" class="form-control" ng-model="student.lastName" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dob" class="col-sm-3 control-label">DoB</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="date" id="dob" class="form-control" ng-model="student.DoB" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="gender" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select id="gender" class="form-control" ng-model="student.gender">
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <span><b>Training Location</b></span>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input value="online" type="radio" name="training" ng-model="student.trainingType" />Online</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input value="onsite" type="radio" name="training" ng-model="student.trainingType" />OnSite</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <span><b>Main Subjects</b></span>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.maths" />Maths</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.physics" />Physics</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.chemistry" />Chemistry</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-3" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" ng-click="resetForm()">
</form>
```

Comment: what happens when you change your routes to `.otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/RouteNotMapped"
            });`

Comment: It's still the same @AlexanderHiggins

Comment: Are you getting the authentication alert? Can your browse directly to `/student/someusername` ?

Comment: I get an error that loginController is not registered but I already checked the strings to see that it's the same with the registered controller in $routeProvider

Comment: No, I can't directly accessed /student/someusername

Comment: Cool so trying that got you an error which helped you figure out the problem.

Comment: Yeah Thanks but I'm still confused why it's not working when the controller definition is inside app.config definition :)

Answer (score 1):

And fortunately I found out the solution myself. It now works when I transferred the definition of controller outside app.config. But I wonder why it affects the definition of the controller when it's inside app.config. I just follow this one in the tutorial but I don't know if they have a mistake over this one or it's just the browser. Can someone explain me?

**Edited Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app="ngRoutingDemo">
    <h1>Angular Routing Demo</h1>

    <div ng-view>

    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('ngRoutingDemo', ['ngRoute']);
        console.log('Angular Module configured successfully!');
        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            console.log('Diving inside app.config to find the appropriate route');
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            }).when('/student/:username', {
                templateUrl: '/student.html',
                controller: 'studentController'
            }).otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/"
            });

        });

//It's now outside app.config
        app.controller("loginController", function ($scope, $location) {

            $scope.authenticate = function (username) {
                // write authentication code here..
                alert('authenticate function is invoked');
                $location.path('/student/' + username)
            };

        });

        app.controller("studentController", function ($scope, $routeParams) {
            $scope.username = $routeParams.username;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the angular documentation for module: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

> **Module Loading & Dependencies**
>
> A module is a collection of configuration and run blocks which get applied to   the application during the bootstrap process. In its simplest form the module consists of a collection of two kinds of blocks:
>
> Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.
>
> Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system configuration during application run time.